# App Pool Issues and Website redirecting back to login after successful login

Tags: asp.net, authentication, redirect, webforms, application-pool

I have a website developed with asp.net webforms. It uses the asp.net identity for user authentication and management. Also, I set a response cookie once a user is authenticated upon login which is used to track which category the user belongs to (not user role please, I mean a custom category according to my software requirement) and to serve needful data.

The Problem:

Although the website runs fine, it has two particular issues I have been trying best to solve for sometime now

Whenever the website receives much traffic (though not massive):

1. The Server runs into Pool issues. The App Pool will just stop unexpectedly without any traceable cause. Until I access my hosting panel to restart the App Pool. Much inconveniencing and embarrassing sometimes.
2. Users are unable to login successfully. From my tracking, I observe the user is being authenticated, but is being returned to login page again while he's supposed to be taken to the dashboard. If a user enters invalid credentials at this point, Authentication failure text will be revealed which means that the authentication is working fine.

I'm not sure what the cause of the issue above is.

Although one of my code logic is to check the response Cookie I set whenever the user is authenticated, if it is empty then the user is signed out. But I don't know how to confirm if this could be the issue for problem #2.

I'll appreciate any response in attempt to save the situation.

For the pool issue, I have tried to ensure that all my database connections I use the Using...EndUsing for the SQLCommand Object.

For the redirect, I have checked my code logic over and over again

Comment: Well, if you have some code error, that will OFTEN trigger a app pool re-start, and if that occures, then session is gone. I think the best solution (untill you figure out what is going wrong) is to enable SQL server based session management. That means that any error in code some place MIGHT trigger a app-pool restart, but you don't care since if you enable SQL session management, then it will not matter, and their session variables will remain intact. You should enable a global error hander, and have it email you when an error occurs along with the error information.

Comment: You can probably find some clues of the Errors in the Event Viewer of the server.  You could also increase the "Rapid-Fail Protection" interval (or disable it) in the Advanced Settings of the AppPool. in IIS. But finding and fixing the error is very much preferred!

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @AlbertD.Kallal, how do I do what you pointed out? Can you possibly explain or point me to a resource?